# Servlet Classnotfound in eclipse java Dynamic Project build on Maven

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, servlets

> I am very new to web world and so I was trying to create a simple
>   JSP-Servlet based webpage but wanted to build the same on maven. I
>   google almost everything but eclipse is throwing exception while
>   trying to create eclipse maven project , while trying to create
>   dynamic project from Eclipse , it worked but couldn;t find an easy way
>   to integrate Servlet along with JSP page, Finally I found a way , I
>   created a dynamic web project in eclipe, then created required java
>   directory in the project and compiled with maven included the servlet
>   dependency. Is it a proper way to do it , or is there some extremely
>   easy way to create dynamic web project in maven which includes JSP ,
>   Servlet both.

Now once I am done with my approach may be broken approach , just after clicking on the first page button , getting

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Controllertest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.test.Controller
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So here is my structure of the code-
[image]

> my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>de.vogella.wtp.jsp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>ShowAll.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description>Controllertest</description>
        <display-name>Controllertest</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Controllertest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.abc.test.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controllertest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Controllertest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and my servlet-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controllertest
 */
public class Controllertest extends HttpServlet {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private static String DELETE_JSP = "/Delete.jsp";
      private static String EDIT_JSP = "/Edit.jsp";
      private static String SHOWALL_JSP = "/ShowAll.jsp";


      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward="";
        // Get a map of the request parameters
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map parameters = request.getParameterMap();
        if (parameters.containsKey("delete")){
          forward = DELETE_JSP;
        } else if (parameters.containsKey("edit")){
          forward = EDIT_JSP;
        } else {
          forward = SHOWALL_JSP;
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
      }
}
```

I don;t think any more tweaks I did .
for better clarification here is my eclipse Deployment Assembly
[image]

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>CounterWebApp3</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CounterWebApp3 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>CounterWebApp3</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                <include>**/*.css</include>
                                <include>**/*.html</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Provide full stack trace. Also, you have a mapping for `com.abc.test.Controller`, but your servlet class is `Controllertest`.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually the problem is the output classes are getting generated
>   inside target/classes.Once I copied the classes from target to web-inf
>   , it worked.

Now I need to know the reason and then need to figure that out in my set-up.

Comment: How do you build your project? you should use mvn [clean] package to properly build Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create your servlet class by right click on project –> New –> Class, not with the right click on project –> New –> Servlet option in Eclipse.

I have tried it and it is working fine